# divide rectangle into n equal parts

Tags: math

i want to code a video platform and have a problem and can't think of a solution right now.

I want to divide a rectangle into equal parts

Came up with a solution for a square but i am unable to come up with a solution for different ratios.

Maybe u guys can help me.

example:

```
 BAD                                GOOD

n=4
________                            ________
| | | | |                           |   |   |   
| | | | |                           |---|---|
|_|_|_|_|                           |___|___|

n=2
________                             ________
|   |   |                           |       |
|   |   |                           |       |
|   |   |                           |–––––––|
|   |   |                           |       |
|___|___|                           |_______|
```

Comment: What is wanted solution for n=31 or another prime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let X be the width of the rectangle and let Y be the height. Let the goal be to divide this rectangle into N rectangles of equal area whose sides are as close to equal as possible.

The solution is not difficult. First, find all factors of the N. Then, write N as a product of two numbers A and B such that A and B are as close as possible (that is, there is no other choice A' and B' such that |A' - B'| < |A - B|). Assume we chose A > B. All we have to do is put A - 1 lines along the long side of the rectangle, and B - 1 lines along the short side.

For example: n = 4, A = 2 and B = 2 is optimal, so you put A - 1 = 1 and B - 1 = 1 lines along each side of the rectangle (as in your GOOD column for n = 4).

For example: n = 21, A = 7 and B = 3 is optional, so you'd put 6 lines along the long edge of the rectangle and 2 lines along the short edge, equally spaced:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

Of course, for prime values of N, you are not going to get a very nice solution, but then there is no nice solution in that case. In such cases - where A and B are very very different and the rectangle's dimensions are not similarly different - you might want to choose another solution that doesn't require all rectangles have the same side lengths. You could do better by allowing 2 or 3 kinds of rectangles, or more, into the solution, for instance.

Comment: It occurs to me that this makes rectangles that approximate as nearly as possible the original rectangle. It does not divide the rectangle into rectangles that are as close to squares as possible. To do that instead, you'd want to choose A and B such that their ratio is as close as possible to the ratio of X and Y, and then lay out the lines accordingly.